# How to define a class from json/dict

Tags: python, json, class, config, metaprogramming

I want to define class from a dict/json file, how can I do that?

As a simple:

```
dict1={'class name':'Foo1','attribute':{"att1":"float","att2":"integer"}}
dict1={'class name':'Foo2','attribute':{"att3":"float","att4":"integer"}}
```

And I would like to have two classes being created:

```
class Foo1:
...
class Foo2:
...
```

Comment: I have to ask the counter-question: why would you do that? That is a terrible idea! You should have classes defined in the code and only data passed around in json. Why would you have a class defined in json?

Comment: I want to define a few pair of classes that each pair is handling data stream processing on different stages ( calculation vs storage), and want to keep the pair some what easy to manage and being consistent, i think provide essential parameters for the classes in a config file is easy and clean, and maybe simple to expand in future.

Comment: But then you don't have to _create_ a class from json. You can have a number of classes in the code and then create an _instance_ of one of them, based on the class name in the json.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's `type` to convert your dictionary to a python `class` like below.

```
dict1 = {'class name': 'Foo1', 'attribute': {"att1": "float", "att2": "integer"}}
dict2 = {'class name': 'Foo2', 'attribute': {"att3": "float", "att4": "integer"}}


Foo1 = type(dict1['class name'], (object,), dict1['attribute'])
Foo2 = type(dict2['class name'], (object,), dict2['attribute'])

foo1 = Foo1()
foo2 = Foo2()
print(foo1.att1, foo2.att3)
```

**Output:**

```
float float
```

**Alternative approach:** https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-a-dictionary-into-a-class/

Comment: I'd like to have something more flexible, as I might also create some custom method accordingly.